# Windows Phone turn flash on in background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-process, flashlight

I am working on a tools app and I need a way to turn on the camera flash when I click a tile, then keep it on in the background and turn it off once I click the tile again.

I don't need any help with the tile yet all I want to know is what I can do to turn on the flash and then keep it on. All the examples I have seen thus far simply pretend to be a camera and then turn the flash on.

Do you know of anything?

PS. I am planning on making this for WP 7 and 8 but if you know of a way that will on work on WP 8 that will also help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.

While the app is running, you can control the camera and turn on the flash. But as soon as you exit the app (Back button) or the app is suspended (due to a phone call or by pressing the Start button), the use of the camera is suspended.

Windows Phone does have [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) but these are very limited and [do not allow access to the camera API at all (and many other APIs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).